# The JasperReports engine is adding extra whitespace

Tags: jasper-reports

I have a Jasper report which contains several pages with some freeflow data pulled from a database. For certain pages there is additional whitespace and I'm not sure where this is coming from. I have trimmed the data, and there is padding but this is extra Whitespace:

The section of my report looks like:

```
<textField textAdjust="StretchHeight">
<reportElement positionType="Float" x="0" y="150" width="555" height="10" />
<box padding="5" topPadding="20" leftPadding="0"/>
<textElement markup="styled">
    <font size="14"/>
</textElement>
<textFieldExpression><![CDATA["<b><u>Questions:</u></b>"]]></textFieldExpression>
</textField>
<componentElement>
<reportElement positionType="Float" x="0" y="160" width="200" height="20" />
<jr:list printOrder="Vertical">
<datasetRun subDataset="questionDetails">
<dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRMapCollectionDataSource($F{questions})]]></dataSourceExpression>
</datasetRun>
<jr:listContents height="30" width="555">
<textField textAdjust="StretchHeight">
<reportElement positionType="Float" x="0" y="0" width="555" height="10" />
<box padding="5" leftPadding="0"/>
<textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{question}]]></textFieldExpression>
</textField>
<textField textAdjust="StretchHeight">
<reportElement positionType="Float" x="0" y="10" width="555" height="10"/>
<box padding="5" leftPadding="0"/>
<textElement markup="styled"/>
<textFieldExpression><![CDATA["<b>Response:</b> " + $F{response}]]></textFieldExpression>
</textField>
<textField textAdjust="StretchHeight">
<reportElement positionType="Float" x="0" y="20" width="555" height="10">
<printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{comment}.length() > 0]]></printWhenExpression>
</reportElement>
<box padding="5" leftPadding="0" bottomPadding="20"/>
<textElement markup="styled"/>
<textFieldExpression><![CDATA["<b>Comment:</b> " + net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRStringUtil.xmlEncode($F{comment}.trim())]]></textFieldExpression>
</textField>
</jr:listContents>
</jr:list>
</componentElement>
```

This looks like this on one page with some additional, unnecessary space:

[image]

And looks like this on another:

[image]

Any ideas?